# Nested Classes, Nested Lists, or Maps?

Tags: java, arrays, list, class, arraylist

After reading through nested classes, nested lists, and mapping, I'm still having trouble deciding the proper method to use and even still, how to implement those three methods.

Objective: tracking statistics of multiple services up time from a log file. Each service status change is on one line and contains the Name, the oldStatus, newStatus, and timeChanged

In the end, I'd like to see the time between these lines but for now I'm simply trying to organize the data properly.

Currently, I'm going down the road of using a class and here is the building of it:

```
public class Services {
    private List<String> AllServices = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Initial thought of adding another list here, containing
    // the variables, but how would I associate that to the
    // service above?
    private List<String> ServiceStatus;



    public boolean AddService(String name) {
        if (!AllServices.contains(name)) {
            AllServices.add(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<String> GetServices() {
        return AllServices;
    }
}
```

That is all find and good. As the parser discovers a new service, it adds it to the list so there aren't duplicates. Then, I moved on to adding each time it find a service status has changed. I can't figure out how, for each service, to store that data.

I guess I could liken it to using a database with the unique identifier being the service name, holding records for each time the status changes, what it changed to, and the time. Once I get that down, I can start comparing the times between.

Initial thought of adding another list here, containing the variables, but how would I associate that to each service?

I considered arrays, but in Java they seem rather static, as in having to resize them to add more data. I've since forgotten the work around for this in PHP, but from my limited past experience I recall being able to build up and use arrays such as:

```
statusChanged = myServices["TheService"][i][date];
statusChangedTo = myServices["TheService"][i][new_status];
statusChangedTo = myServices["OtherService"][i][date];
statusChangedTo = myServices["OtherService"][i][new_status];

AllServices
 |- TheService
 |   |- TimeDate
 |       | - New Status
 |       | - Old Status
 |- OtherService
     |- TimeDate
         | - New Status
         | - Old Status
```

Which lead me down the path of using extended Classes. I could have Services and also Service. Services would result in just having a List of services, but then how does Service again associate it's underlying variables to specific services listed in the parent Services class?

Again, I feel like I'm overthinking this after reading too many examples that are similar but not to what I'm trying to accomplish. Or, I'm just completely off the wall entirely and there could be a far better method.

Comment: `myServices.get("TheService").newStatus` would be a more "Java Way". Anyway, Java is not PHP.

Comment: *"It adds it to the list so there aren't duplicates."* It will be better to use `HashSet` in this case.

Comment: Side note: read about naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase, not AllServices for example!

Comment: @user2864740 Indeed, it is not PHP. I'm trying to learn the Java way and completely agree. I think you ultimately answered my question with that hint too.

Comment: @GhostCat I'll look into HashSet more deeply, thank you. Hah! Thank you for the side note too. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: IMO You'd be better off thinking about a SQL DB solution for storing/organizing all your data first. Do you know SQL?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Again going back to using PHP a few years ago, I've dabbled with it enough to be able to store this information. Using a database would make this easier, but I haven't interacted with one in Java and setting up a database server for this little task seems a bit heavy.

Comment: @mrUlrik If you listened to the Blue Oyster Cult, they'd tell you "Don't fear the SQL"! (Yuck yuck yuck) but in all seriousness you'd be much better served in the long run (IMO) going back and working on your SQL skills on this one. Hint: Think foreign keys!!!

Comment: @mrUlrik, You can use some embedded DB (like HSQLDB). If so, there is no the standalone DB server. See http://hsqldb.org/ for more information.

Comment: @ControlAltDel In the end, I'm using a database. I accept your I told you so. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use any DB to persist logged events. It is preferrable solution in case of many services with many events.

Otherwise, I provide a few steps for storing them in memory:

First of all, you should to divide data by name of service. Use `Map<K,V>` for it.

Secondly, I suggest you to combine `oldStatus`, `newStatus` and `timeChanged` into `ServiceEvent` class:

```
public class ServiceEvent {
    private final String oldStatus;
    private final String newStatus;
    private final DateTime timeChanged;
    // methods...
}
```

It is convinient to order events by `timeChanged` with `Comparator` in case of unordered sequence of events:

```
public class ServiceEventComparator implements Comparator<ServiceEvent> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ServiceEvent e1, ServiceEvent e2) {
        return e1.getTimeChanged().compareTo(e2.getTimeChanged());
    }
}
```

Thus, your `ServiceEventRepository` can be like this:

```
public class ServiceEventRepository {
    private Map<String, SortedSet<ServiceEvent>> storage = new HashMap<>();

    public void addEvent(String service, ServiceEvent event) {
        SortedSet<ServiceEvent> events = storage.get(service);
        if (events == null) {
            events = new TreeSet<ServiceEvent>(new ServiceEventComparator());
            storage.put(service, events);
        }
        events.add(event);
    }
}
```

Use simple `List<ServiceEvent>` if sequence of events has natural order.

Note that the `ServiceEventRepository` above is not *thread safe*.

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you very much. I'm still playing around with it--I should have mentioned I'm an amateur so I've got a bit of digging to do.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to ask specific questions about it.

Comment: Ultimately, I needed a database (I accept all of your 'I told you so's). But I didn't want to waste @Gregory.K time so I implemented this. It is exactly what I was originally looking for.  Though, when I went down this road, I was working with only 3 files. Now it's over 100 files and over 20,000 lines. I didn't see that coming, so, I'll be moving to SQLite or greater. Thank you for the education and time! And this is still excellent for someone needing to store, say, attributes of an object. Person <- (height, weight, age)